# Calculate Beta with two variables with different length in R

Tags: r, dataframe, beta, variance

I am trying to calculate the beta for a fund with a customized index in R. The customized index is made from a few different indexes. The index has data from before the fund, so when I am trying to calculate the beta by using

```
beta <- cov(data$fund,data$index, use =
            "pairwise.complete.obs")/var(data$index, use =
            "pairwise.complete.obs")
```

I get the variance from the whole period of the index. The covariance gets correct. I assume that I need to make the customized index to fit the data of the fund, but I can not find any answer on how I am doing this. My data is from latest to newest, so I need the start of the customized index to be NA to where the funds data starts. I need a function that gives me a column with the customized index with only data at the dates where the fund also has data.

Example of the data (random numbers):

```
Date     Fund        Customized Index 
01.01     NA             100
01.02     50             105
```

I want it the customized index column to be:

```
Date     Fund        Customized Index
01.01     NA              NA
01.02     50              105
```

**Update: Solution**

I used "ifelse" on making the customized index. This works just as the same way as =IF does in Excel.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a look at these tips on how to produce a [minimum, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as well as this post on [creating a great example in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: UPDATE: Solution: used "ifelse" on making the customized index. This works just as the same way as =IF does in Excel.

Comment: if you have solved your own problem, please post the solution as an answer ...